# Redirecting php variables to new webpage + use

Tags: php, variables, redirect, post, web

Here is my code below(php):

```
$answers = $_POST;

  $url1 = "http://www.example.com/page";

  $var1 = 12;  
  $var2 = 12;  
  $var3 = 8;  
  $var4 = 10;  
  $var5 = 4;  
  $var6 = 2;  
  $var7 = 1;  
  $var8 = 6;  
  $var9 = 12;   
  $var10 = 10;   
  $url2 = $url1.$var1.$var2.$var3.$var4.$var5.$var6.$var7.$var8.$var9.$var10;

  header("location:$url2");
```

---

The users will click this site and they will be redirected to another page. I am trying to get these variables to be transfered to the other page. It is currently displaying the variable as ' ' . Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: echo those out, what do they give you? ;-) bit of error checking would help too. That gives you `http://www.example.com/results/121281042161210` btw. No idea what you're trying to do here though.

Comment: you sure you've a webserver/php installed? If so, you accessing this as `http://localhost` or `file:///`? Two different animals here. Plus, no idea why you've included a $_POST in there.

Comment: as per your edit: that gives me `http://www.example.com/page121281042161210`

Comment: you doing to respond to comment #2 here? I'm betting on that. *"Any help would be greatly appreciated"* - You asked for help, I gave it to you. Or are you facepalming yourself right now?

Comment: @RiggsFolly edited above comment ;-) `NOW()` I'm gone ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think OP has gone to lunch, not seen for 12 minutes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I had to come back just one more time ^

Comment: My boomerang may be lost, but my @Fred-ii- will always return

Answer (score -1):

Aussuming that you running your code on server which is able to run `PHP` scripts. Keep both files in same directory. On my localhost I run this script by following url - http://localhost/test/page1.php

First File Code (`Page1.php`)

```
<?php
    //this is page1.php
    $url1 = "page2.php";

    $var1 = 12;  
    $var2 = 12;  
    $var3 = 8;  
    $var4 = 10;  
    $var5 = 4;  
    $var6 = 2;  
    $var7 = 1;  
    $var8 = 6;  
    $var9 = 12;   
    $var10 = 10;   
    $url2 = $url1."?var1=".$var1."&var2=".$var2;

    header("location:$url2");

?>
```

Second file code (`page2.php`)

```
<?php
    //this is page2.php
    $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
    echo "var 1 = ".$var1;
    echo "<br/>";
    $var2 = $_GET['var2'];
    echo "var 2 = ".$var2;

?>
```

You will be redirected to page2.php.

Comment: Did you read this in the question? *"It is currently displaying the variable as ' '"*

Comment: I'm not damn sure but I think Without '?' query string variables will not get parsed.

Comment: even without that, the OP gets `''`. POST/GET doesn't matter; they're getting empty `''` and they will get parsed if a webserver/php is installed and using the right URL and not a `file:///`.

Comment: I think OP needs to add code of second page, how he is trying to get variables

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added this piece of code to my code and unfortunately, I got the same output as before, a single space. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Assuming that you are running script on server which is able to run PHP script... Just last suggestion and i will be out... ;-) try edited code